# Why can't I return this array?

Tags: c, arrays, return

Why am I getting the following errors?

```
randmst.c: In function ‘main’:

randmst.c:41: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

randmst.c: In function ‘createGraph’:

randmst.c:84: warning: return from incompatible pointer type

randmst.c:84: warning: function returns address of local variable
```

`createGraph()` creates an array of pointers (called `VertexPointer`) to `structs`.  Once it's created, I'm having trouble passing it back to `main()`.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    //command line arguments
    int test = atoi(argv[1]);
    int numpoints = atoi(argv[2]);
    int numtrials = atoi(argv[3]);
    int dimension = atoi(argv[4]);

    //perform trials, put results in an array
    int i;
    int trials[dimension];
    for(i = 0; i < numtrials; i++){
        VertexPointer graph[numpoint= createGraph(numpoints, dimension);

        //testing
        int y;
        int i;
        for(y = 0; y < numpoints; y++){
            for(i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
                printf("%f \n", (*graph[y]).loc[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }


}



//an array of pointers holding the vertices of the graph
VertexPointer
createGraph(int numpoints, int dimension){
    //seed the psuedo-random number generator
    srand(time(NULL));

    //declare an array for the vertices
    VertexPointer graph[numpoints];

    //create the vertices in the array
    int x;
    int z;
    for(x = 0; x < numpoints; x++){
        //create the vertex
        VertexPointer v;
        v = (VertexPointer)malloc(sizeof(Vertex));
        (*v).key = 100;
        //(*v).prev = 0;
        //multiple dimensions
        for(z=0; z < dimension; z++){
            (*v).loc[z] = rand_float();
        }
        //put the pointer in the array
        graph[x] = v;
    }
    return graph;
}
```

Comment: Because of this: `warning: function returns address of local variable`

Comment: Is there a copying error? `VertexPointer graph[numpoint= createGraph(numpoints, dimension);` is not a valid statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C does not allow you to return arrays. Even if it did, your code declares that `createGraph` returns a `VertexPointer`, not an array of them. `malloc` an array of pointers, change your code to return `VertexPointer *`, and use a pointer instead of an array in `main`.

```
VertexPointer *
createGraph(int numpoints, int dimension) {
    ...
    VertexPointer *graph = malloc(numpoints * sizeof(*graph));
    ...
    return graph;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ...
    VertexPointer *graph = createGraph(numpoints, dimension);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nit: C lets you return arrays, it just treats them as pointers, and if you return a local array, it's undefined behavior because the array gets deallocated when you exit the function.

Comment: @user3303729: I'm not considering that "returning an array".

Comment: There are times when it's useful to return a static array defined in the function (at least, if thread-safe is not required).